# Understanding the construction 〜ていることもあるとかないとか

Tags: grammar

> 寿季「挨拶列、かなり長かったようだし」
>
> ちなみに挨拶列というのは、物販とは違い作家本人にファンが挨拶出来る列のことである。
>
> この中に企業の人間も混ざるため、人気な作家は閉館まで対応し**ていることもあるとかないとか**。

The speaker is at a comic market.

How should I understand the construction 〜ていることもあるとかないとか?

I think 〜ていることがある means

```
there are times when ~ / sometimes ~/ occasionally ~
```

I’m not sure because I seldom see ている form used with the ことがある structure. I’m more familiar with dictionary form+ことがある.

More importantly, is the あるとかないとか roughly equivalent to あるらしい or あるかもしれない (seems to be)?

Comment: It's a lot of words to say "it depends"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right in that あるとかないとか is roughly equivalent to あるらしい (not really あるかもしれない).

The particular sentence can be considered as an omission of the ending あるとかないとか（**聞いた/言っている**）= (**I heard/They say**) there are cases ...

Generally とかないとか is an expression to add uncertainty to the preceding statement.  ない part may be different depending on the preceding sentence.

- 彼は外国に住んでたことがあるとかないとか *I heard he used to live abroad*
- その効果はＬＳＤにも匹敵するとかしないとか。(from [here](https://hinative.com/ja/questions/3343572)) *They say that the effect is comparable to LSD*

---

In terms of meaning, とかなんとか=*or something* is more or less the same. In the examples, あるとかなんとか/するとかなんとか may be used without changing the meaning much.

---

There are cases where とかないとか means more literally *or not*.

- **意味があるとかないとか**考える前に *before thinking whether **it makes sense or not***
- **運動するとかしないとか**いうより食事量が多すぎる ***It is not about whether you do some exercise or not**, but about your eating too much*.